# Can i install juju zookeeper on maas server itself?

Tags: server, juju, maas

Is it possible to have juju zookeeper on maas server? I dont wanna have 2 separate servers for maas and juju.

Answer (score 1):

Juju, as of 1.1.0, no longer uses Zookeeper. What you're referring to is the bootstrap node. At this time it isn't possible to locate the bootstrap node outside of the environment. However, you can deploy a service to the bootstrap node using the `--to` flag. It's not recommended, but if you know that the two won't collide, you can `juju deploy --to 0 <service>` to have a service shared on the bootstrap node.